# Dawing crystal structure

Tags: software-recommendation

I need to draw a face centred cubic (FCC) and one zincblende crystal structure. Which software shall I use to draw those on Ubuntu ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Inkscape](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/inkscape).

You could do a 3D effect if needed using gradients, e.g. [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Vector-8-Ball-With-Inkscape).

Use the clone feature once you have made your "atom"